# Shell command executes differently in Build and PipeLine section

Tags: bash, shell, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have placed the below shell script line in 2 jenkins jobs.

Job 1. Under Build section.

Job 2. Under PipeLine section.

```
Line_count=$(bash -c "ssh $node1 'grep -nr \"Testcase Summary\" ${logs_path}/result.log |cut -d \":\" -f1'")
```

But it executes the same command in different ways, Below is the console output from 2 jobs:

Job 1 :

```
bash -c 'ssh node1 '\''grep -nr "Testcase Summary" /root/logs/result.log |cut -d ":" -f1'\'''
```

Job 2:

```
bash -c 'ssh node1 '\''grep -nr Testcase' 'Summary /root/logs/result.log | cut -d : -f1'\'''
```

Why the shell script line kept inside pipeline is executed differently? Did I miss anything here?

Comment: The string " \"" is not interpreted by the same way in "classical" job and in pipeline, I guess this is linked to the groovy interpretation done under pipeline side

Comment: Thank you! Yes the interpretation was different in freestyle and pipeline job.